# Html table dimensions gets disturbed on different system

Tags: html, css, struts2, css-tables

I am developing struts2, Hibernate based web application, but its HTML, specially dynamic table, gets disturbed when it is accessed on different resolution systems.

I have already tried display tag, fixing headers of table and using percentage instead of pixels in CSS but still its happening, I want make a fixed design where all components should remain same on any resolution or it can auto adjust.

Comment: Post the code and describe the problem. Without it isn't possible to help.

Answer (score 0):

try using responsive tables these tables align according to devices and resolutions.
here is a plugin -  [LINK](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables)

or if you want to do it on your own look at media queries [LINK](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

or take a look at the answer here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723617/responsive-tables-the-smart-way/19724087#19724087)