# HTML css table responsive with different rows

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am building simple list of items from db.
Each item from this list contains 5 elements.
On desktop screens I have enough space to display them all in a row like this:

[image: current desktop preview]
In principle sample above is generated using this css table:

```
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell img">PHOTO</div>
            <div class="divTableCell title">TITLE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell price">PRICE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell bids">BIDS</div>
            <div class="divTableCell timeleft">TIME LEFT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.divTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

I am looking for a solution using CSS media query to display results in a different way for mobile:

```
-------------------------
IMG | Title
    | Price Bids TimeLeft
-------------------------
```

[image]

Every row is generated on backend, so I can change entire html structure, but I dont have any control over what width its displayed for, is there any option to achieve sth like this using just css and media queries? Can you point me to right direction?

Comment: Do the answers to [Responsive tables, the smart way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19723617/1016716) help?

Comment: Thabk you!! I sure using information from responses there i will be avle to solve my problem.

Comment: Should I post working answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to make a media query or no? I am just going to give you a hint how to do it:

[HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) for displaying/aligning the div

[HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for media query

Try to play with the display attribute in the CSS of the div tag.

PS

Do not forget to do the change in the media query otherwise it will change it all.

Good luck :)

Comment: Yes I have tried but coulnd get result as i wanted. I will read more.